# Back door frame no longer square

Tags: doors, exterior, structural

I live on the 3rd (top) floor of a condo building.  Our back door - which opens to the outside, is not square.  The building was built in 2006 and the drywall around the door at the corners is cracked and separating (the corner tape is clearly coming away).  There is visible light at the bottom of the door and it does not close properly (rubs in several places).  My suspicion is that the building has settled (this didn't happen overnight) and this is a structural issue.

So my question is twofold.  First, does my suspicion sound correct (I know it's hard to judge based on a brief description)?  Second, if I am right, what is the best way to deal with this?  I don't see any obvious exterior signs of cracking, but I'm guessing this can't be good.  It's likely the condo association's problem to address, but if there is anything I can do to alleviate the issue, I'd like to.

Comment: Typically in condo's, anything exterior is common element and would be handled by the condo corp. Unless your case is different or you have authorization, I wouldn't start playing around with it

Comment: Not only should it be the condo association's problem, you should get on them and make sure they hire a structural engineer to evaluate what's happened and how to correctly resolve it. Your doorframe cracking and going out of square is a symptom - the problem may be **considerably** more serious.

Answer (score 1):

It's time to take photographs, measurements, and contact the association.  Take measurements periodically.  Check other windows & doors for similar problems, and ask your downstairs neighbors about the same.  The HA needs to get to the bottom of this, and only they can do it.